# string in JSON uncaught syntaxerror

Tags: javascript, json

I have problem with array of JSON object in my javascript code, here is the code

```
[{"id":"ID", "lat":"LAT", "lon":"LON", "zip":"ZIP", "text":"TEXT"}]
```

the problem appear in "text" object, when the string contain "in" work it say "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"
here is the complete code :

```
[{"id":"1", "lat":"43.19716728250127", "lon":"-119.53125", "zip":"40219", "text":"Testing, Hello World"},{"id":"2", "lat":"46.92025531537451", "lon":"-119.443359375", "zip":"40222", "text":"hello world"},{"id":"3", "lat":"39.16414104768742", "lon":"-82.529296875", "zip":"", "text":"Choice Roof Contractor
&lt;br&gt;Based in Mansfield, OH"}]
```

Comment: What code are you using to process this? `in` is a perfectly legitimate string token in Javascript.

Comment: Can't reproduce — http://jsbin.com/ElaXalo/1/ — when you create a reduced test case, you need to provide enough information to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why don't you post here the ACTUAL string you're using. Why would you put a screenshot of something different?

Comment: Please post the text and not an image.

Comment: ok sorry, here is text version {"id":"3", "lat":"39.16414104768742", "lon":"-82.529296875", "zip":"", "text":"Choice Roof Contractor
&lt;br&gt;Based in Mansfield, OH"}

Comment: complete code

[{"id":"1", "lat":"43.19716728250127", "lon":"-119.53125", "zip":"40219", "text":"Testing, Hello World"},{"id":"2", "lat":"46.92025531537451", "lon":"-119.443359375", "zip":"40222", "text":"hello world"},{"id":"3", "lat":"39.16414104768742", "lon":"-82.529296875", "zip":"", "text":"Choice Roof Contractor
&lt;br&gt;Based in Mansfield, OH"}]

Comment: Works perfectly fine: See http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/8DB99/

Comment: HTML special characters are fine, too. http://jsfiddle.net/8DB99/2/

Comment: i loop the array to get every json object and put the properties in another line in the code.
why you keep down vote me? i've edited it

Comment: @DarielPratama We're more interested in the code that you use to do that - how exactly do you loop through the JSON, and what do you do with it?

Comment: @DarielPratama Because obviously there is something you're not telling us. Include all relevant info, eg. loop code.

Comment: here is loop look like http://jsfiddle.net/tSRPV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that JavaScript does not support multiline strings. Make sure that all of your strings are on one line.

```
[{"id":"1", "lat":"43.19716728250127", "lon":"-119.53125", "zip":"40219", "text":"Testing, Hello World"},{"id":"2", "lat":"46.92025531537451", "lon":"-119.443359375", "zip":"40222", "text":"hello world"},{"id":"3", "lat":"39.16414104768742", "lon":"-82.529296875", "zip":"", "text":"Choice Roof Contractor
<br>Based in Mansfield, OH"}]
```

This should be like this :

```
[{"id":"1", "lat":"43.19716728250127", "lon":"-119.53125", "zip":"40219", "text":"Testing, Hello World"},{"id":"2", "lat":"46.92025531537451", "lon":"-119.443359375", "zip":"40222", "text":"hello world"},{"id":"3", "lat":"39.16414104768742", "lon":"-82.529296875", "zip":"", "text":"Choice Roof Contractor<br>Based in Mansfield, OH"}]
```

---

A simple example:

```
// Will NOT work!
var str =  "This is a
multiline string";

// Will work
var str = "This is not a multiline string";

// Will work
var str = "This is a " + 
"multiline string";
```

Comment: may i post some screenshot of how it looks like in my real HTML source?

Comment: @DarielPratama - What's with the screenshots? You are dealing with text no? Just post the actual text you're using... With your example jsFiddle - all I needed to do to make it work was to get rid of that line break.

Comment: @DarielPratama Why a screenshot? Just put it in a fiddle. You can then easilly debug yourself.

Comment: there is no line break in actual source, all code is put in just one line.

Comment: @DarielPratama - look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tSRPV/1/). There was also an issue with your loop - it was going over the index because you used `<=`

Comment: ok sorry, i fixed the loop parameter but still the problem hit me. am i drunk? because i don't see any linebreak in my source code (browser source)

Comment: deleted the "in" text and problem is away now, but why? it's not funny to not allow "in" text

Comment: @DarielPratama - look at you ACTUAL source code - not the text that the browser shows you. The code you originally posted in your question DOES contain a line break.

Comment: ok Lix, thank you very much. i will take at it one more time, wish me luck ;)
also thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working javascript. There is a linebreak in http://jsfiddle.net/tSRPV/ after *Choice Roof Contractor* causing the issue.:

```
var _json = [{
    "id": "1",
    "lat": "43.19716728250127",
    "lon": "-119.53125",
    "zip": "40219",
    "text": "Testing, Hello World"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "lat": "46.92025531537451",
    "lon": "-119.443359375",
    "zip": "40222",
    "text": "hello world"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "lat": "39.16414104768742",
    "lon": "-82.529296875",
    "zip": "",
    "text": "Choice Roof Contractor &lt;br&gt;Based in Mansfield, OH"
}];

for (i = 0; i < _json.length; i++) {
    console.log(_json[i].text);
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/8DB99/)